# how to convert "2021-09-01T14:37:40.537Z" into "2021-09-01T14:37:40.5370000+00:00" in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to convert the string "**2021-09-01T14:37:40.537Z**" into "**2021-09-01T14:37:40.5370000+00:00**" in python.we have a hive table which is have the datetime in the format of "2021-09-01T14:37:40.537Z" but we want to convert that into "2021-09-01T14:37:40.5370000+00:00" format in python.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this.  This is a simple string problem, right?  `s = s.replace('Z','0000+00:00')`

Answer (score 1):

### General Solution

The `datetime` module has methods for converting datetimes to and from string representations with arbitrary formats. Specifically, `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` converts from string to `datetime` object, and `datetime.strftime(format)` converts from `datetime` to string. By providing different formats to each method, we can convert between them.

```python3
from datetime import datetime


inp = "2021-09-01T14:37:40.537Z"
date = datetime.strptime(inp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
output = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f0+00:00")
```

Note that this doesn't take into account timezones. If some entries in your table use time zones other than GMT+00:00, a differnt solution is required.

### Alternative solution

In this case, since the two specified formats are so similar, a simpler solution would suffice, although it wouldn't work for other cases. Simply trim the final `Z` from the input string and append `0000+00:00` as follows:

```python3
inp = "2021-09-01T14:37:40.537Z"
output = inp[:-1] + "0000+00:00"
```